# TarsosDSP: Buffer size too small should be at least 7168 #151

Tags: java, tarsosdsp

Although it is written in the documentation that the common buffer size is 1024, 2048;
it is not really running for a size of 1024; and I am getting the error message :

> Buffer size too small should be at least 7168

while calling the following

```
dispatcher = AudioDispatcherFactory.fromDefaultMicrophone(44100 , 1024 , 512);
```

Please, declare if any step is required in order to solve the problem, I need that size for a finer resolution while doing some processing for the buffer data.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem. You can use the finer resolution of the sampling rate (in your case, 44100) but you need to increase the buffer size from 1024 to 7168.

`dispatcher = AudioDispatcherFactory.fromDefaultMicrophone(44100 , 7168, 512);`

That should resolve your issue. You may have to adjust your code for the larger buffer size, but you will have greater resolution.